# Does my walkout basement stud wall need to be flush against the 2" rigid foam board I have installed on the basement concrete wall?

Tags: basement-insulation

I am building an 18' x 14' wood shop in one corner of my basement and one of the side walls is concrete. I am installing 2" rigid foam board on the concrete wall and the way I have the stud wall bottom plate will put my stud wall directly against the rigid foam board. Is that okay or should there be a gap between the two? Three walls in my base basement are concrete slabs bolted together (Pulte basement system).

Comment: I don't see the reason you need to leave a gap.

Comment: Are you not insulating the other 3 walls? Are they already insulated? I presume the "concrete wall" was poured in place while the other walls were pre-fab slabs dropped in by crane?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to leave a gap. In fact, you most likely don't want one at all.

When I did the same for my basement, I put the 2x4s flush against the 2" XPS. This was for several reasons:

- To help hold the XPS against the wall in the event the adhesive holding it to the concrete failed at some point in the future.
- To gain more space in the room (slight as it may be, more is better)
- To eliminate air movement in the wall

The last point is the important one. In temperate areas (I'm in Iowa), the top of that concrete wall is either above or almost above ground level. That makes it cold in the winter. The bottom is far below ground, so it stays relatively stable temperature-wise. So what happens then is you can get convection currents in the wall- warmer air rising, cold air dropping. And then when that warm air hits the colder top, you get condensation. Obviously this isn't desirable.

You want as few gaps for air movement as possible. Dead air is an insulator. I even used cans of spray foam (had them from another project) to seal between the stud and the XPS.

I looked a lot at https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/ when I went to finish my basement and followed their suggestions. I notice some of those have changed since I did mine 6 years ago, but the principles are the same. As stated on that website and others, 2" XPS should eliminate most of the concern with moisture coming from the outside. Therefore, normal concerns of studs against a concrete wall (and them wicking moisture, rotting out prematurely) are mostly, if not completely, eliminated when you use the rigid foam boards.